# How to make the search range dynamic in a vlookup function

Tags: excel, function, google-sheets, spreadsheet, vlookup

I'm trying to make the vlookup function below 'dynamic' by substituting a portion of the sheet name with the value in a cell.

**Current vlookup function**

```
=VLOOKUP($B$4,studentA!A2:D,2)
```

**Desired vlookup function uses the value in cell `C4` to identify the student sheet**

=VLOOKUP($B$4,student`C4`A2:D,2)

Can someone please help me with the syntax for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `INDIRECT`, e.g.

```
=VLOOKUP($B$4,INDIRECT("student"&C4&"!A2:D"),2)
```

Comment: works perfectly! I would have never found indirect(), but now that I know about it, I'll use it all over! Thanks a MILLION!

Comment: @Mr.B be careful, INDIRECT is volatile, in that it will recalc every time Excel Recalcs regardless whether the underlying data has changed or not.  It is powerful, and necessary when referring to sheets in the manner you want in this question.  But there are other non volatile options when the variable involves column or row references.

Comment: @ScottCraner, thanks for the advice! Can you name a few of those options so I can research them? Thanks again!