# Using CONCAT formula after reference to another sheet in same workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get the cell value from another sheet in the same workbook, but instead of being able to do `=US!A3`, I need to be able to make the `A3` dynamic. Ideally, I'd like to do `=US!CONCATENATE(colname," ",rownum))` where rownum would increase by 1 when I pull the formula down. colname is a `vlookup` formula. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: To strictly answer your question, use `INDIRECT`. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48694257/how-to-make-the-search-range-dynamic-in-a-vlookup-function/48694294#48694294). But be aware this is generally not a good solution.

Comment: Even though I answered there is probably an easier method that does not require the volatile formula INDIRECT.  If you show what you have and what you are trying to achieve we may be able to show a better method.

Answer (score 2):

Use INDIRECT:

```
=INDIRECT("US!" & colname & rownum)
```

To get the row number as dynamin we can replace the `rownum` with `ROW()` which will return the row number in which the formula is placed.

Comment: Based on the wording of the question, I don't think OP knows how to get row number, so you could change `rownum` to `ROW()` in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to do here, but you need to adjust how you write your formula. First you need to start with the formula, not the sheet reference.

If you look below you will see I start the formula, and select the cell `A1`, since this is not `$A$1`, it will drag down as I drag it down. Additionally it will drag over as I drag it over. I then put the space you had and this is where your question becomes unclear. I'm unsure what you're trying to combine so I defaulted to cell `B1`.

`=CONCAT(Sheet1!A1," ",Sheet1!B1)`